# issue with contextMenu and CRUD table ngPrime angular2

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I am using `ngprime` in my `angular2` application. I am using `DataTable` for my table view and able to sort, filter but when I try to use `Crud` functionality or `ContextMenu` I am getting errors...

My `AppModule`

```
import {SplitButtonModule} from "primeng/components/splitbutton/splitbutton";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CarsComponent,
    ModsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, FormsModule,
    HttpModule, routing,
    DataTableModule, SharedModule,
    ButtonModule, DropdownModule,
    TieredMenuModule, SplitButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AppConfig, CarsService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (config: AppConfig) => () => config.load(), deps: [AppConfig], multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Sample code used from `ngPrime docs` found [Here](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/contextmenu)

Error ...

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'p-contextMenu'.
1. If 'p-contextMenu' is an Angular component and it has 'model' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-contextMenu' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'visible' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dialog'.
1. If 'p-dialog' is an Angular component and it has 'visible' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-dialog' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Am I missing any imports here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import `ContextMenuModule` and `DialogModule` from `primeng/primeng` in your module imports.

Comment: is there anyway we can change context menu and selectionMode options `<p-dataTable [value]="users" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedUser" [contextMenu]="cm">`  for [hasPermission]="'admin'" selectionMode="multiple" and for others as single ?